# Как захардкодить строку в Jsoup? (проблемы с символами)

Tags: java, jsoup

```
package model;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Created by promoscow on 08.04.17.
 */
public class SchoolStrategy implements Strategy {
    private final String URL_FORMAT = "http://schools.mel.fm/school/gimnazii?schoolType=2%2C5&page=%d";
    private static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6";
    private static final String REFERRER = "none";

    private final String filePath = "./src/" + String.valueOf(this
            .getClass()
            .getPackage()
            .getName()
            .replace(".", "/") + "/schools-test.html");

    protected Document getDocument(int page) throws IOException {
        String b = "http://schools.mel.fm/school/";
        String a = "gimnazii?schoolType=2%2C5&page=";
        String c = b + a + page;
        return Jsoup.connect(c).userAgent(USER_AGENT).referrer(REFERRER).get();
    }

    public void getSchools(String searchString) {
        try {
            Document document = getDocument(0);
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("sc.html"));
            System.out.println(document.html());
            writer.write(document.html());
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что в строке содержится знак процента, из чего появляются лишние символы: 25. Как их убрать, ума не приложу. Перепробовал много чего, не помогает. Помогите!

Jsoup должен распарсить строку

```
http://schools.mel.fm/school/gimnazii?schoolType=2%2C5&page=0
```

вместо этого в него попадает строка

```
http://schools.mel.fm/school/gimnazii?schoolType=2%252C5&page=0
```

Comment: Замените %2C на запятую.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что символ `%` используется для кодированния других (запрещенных) символов в **URL**. В вашем случае последовательность `2%2C5` - это закодированная (экранированная) строка `2,5`. То есть получается, что вы передает уже закодированную строку и её кодируют еще раз.

Решение простое - предавайте не закодированную строку

```
protected Document getDocument(int page) throws IOException {
    String b = "http://schools.mel.fm/school/";
    String a = "gimnazii?schoolType=2,5&page=";
    String c = b + a + page;
    return Jsoup.connect(c).userAgent(USER_AGENT).referrer(REFERRER).get();
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).